# How to customize a SeekBar with minimum value at right side and maximum value at left side

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to customize a Seekbar in android reversely. Minimum value at right and maximum value at left side. Here is the image.

[image]

SeekBar look is not a matter, it could be the default android Seekbar look but the Max and Min value should be inverted. Maximum value will be 10 and minimum value will be 0. If any body have idea please help me.

Comment: if you work on android 11+ you can set on the xml android:rotation="180"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stuff some code.

```
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
                    MAX_VALUE=MAX VALUE-progress;
                    //YOU CAN USED THIS VALUE AND SET INTO SEEKBAR.

                }
```

Comment: I tried putting max value at the left and min value at right and I did some calculation in onProgressChanged() but Seekbar is not moving because of that onProgressChanged() is not getting called.

Comment: I did samething which you mentioned in answer at seProgress() also. Now its working fine.